# htaccess to 301 redirect any URL that ends with 10 numbers

Tags: htaccess, apache, 301-redirect, web-development

How  can I setup `.htaccess` to redirect any URL that ends with 10 digits to home?

For example, I want to redirect these URLs:

- `example.com/abc/1234567890` -> `example.com`
- `example.com/xyz/0001112223` -> `example.com`
- `example.com/foo/bar` -> *ignored*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using mod_rewrite in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \d{10}$ / [R=301,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (regex):
-  `\d` is the shorthand character class for a **d**igit 0-9.
- `{10}` is for 10 of the preceding pattern (ie. 10 digits).
- `$` is an anchor for the end of the string - these digits must appear only at the end of the URL-path.

Whether you should perform a redirect like this is another matter. Multiple redirects to the homepage are likely to be seen as a soft-404 anyway.

Comment: Made it into a list. I find that regex is very hard when just start, IMO this is a bit easier to understand, smaller chunks :) (also trying to create a regex-explained-format-precedent)